# creating a custom plugin task of type Jar

Tags: gradle

I want to publish a jar to artifactory . I am doing this:

```
project.publishing.publications{ task ->
            mavenJava(MavenPublication)  {
                archives makeJar
                }
```

Now, in the makeJar, I am copying a jar from one location to other and just renaming it. It is a task of type Copy but this doesnt work as I get error that the task should be of the type AbstractArchiveTask like a jar task. I want to write a task like this :

```
class MakeJar extends Jar{
  @TaskAction
  def createJar(){
<- code for creating jar ->
}
```

But there is no such gradle task type Jar. I need help to write such a task. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a custom Task class for such an easy functionality:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task renameArtifact(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'jar') {
    from jar.archivePath

    rename '.*', 'renamedFile.jar'

    into 'destDir'
}
```

will compile

```
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── Main.java
```

into

```
├── destDir
│   └── renamedFile.jar
```